# Perform Sping Data Mongo Nested Query using two or more parameters using MongoRepository?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How to perform nested query in MongoDB for the two more fields? I've JSON document like below and looking to query using both the sample2Cd and sample3Cd. How can we do that ?

I was able to write like this, but this doesn't works !!

```
Currency findByCountries_Sample2CdAndsample3CdAndNumberCode
```

Here is my Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c8a65026161ce4970e85035"),
    ..........
    ..............
    "countries" : [ 
        {
            .......
            "sample2Cd" : "AB",
            "sample3Cd" : "ABC",
            "numberCode" : "1"
            ......
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not sure you can achieve that with Spring Data query builder but have you try `findByCountries_Sample2CdAndCountries_sample3CdAndCountries_NumberCode` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using ***@Query*** projection. Here you go !

```
@Query(value = "{'countries.sample2Cd' : ?0, 'countries.sample3Cd' ?1 }")
List<Currency> findByCountriesSample2CdAndSample3Cd(String param1,String param2);
```

Note: Like wise you can multiple parameters and form the query and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `spring repo` method like below.

```
List<Currency> findByCountriesSample2CdAndCountriesSample3CdAndCountriesNumberCode(String param1,String param2, String param3);
```

If the combination will be **unique** then you can change the return type to object instead of the list like below.

```
Currency findByCountriesSample2CdAndCountriesSample3CdAndCountriesNumberCode(String param1,String param2, String param3);
```

Comment: This is not working `Invalid derived query! No property countriesSample2Cd found for type Currency!`